# DataGridTemplateColumn Sorting capabilities Telerik RadDataGrid Windows 8

Tags: xaml, sorting, telerik, microsoft-metro

Normally the Sorting capabilty ( little triangle in the column header + functionality on header click ) comes out of the box if you are using some "typed" column, just by setting the PropertyName to the property from your model. For example it does work for DataGridTextBoxColumn.
But, if you have to use some custom columns enter DataGridTemplateColumn which does not have this PropertyName property.
Question: how can you achieve "easy" sorting on such a column. It should be as easy as setting something like "SortingMemberPath" and that's it.

Do I need to subclass a "typed" column and create my own DataGridCombBoxColumn, for example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the desired functionality by implementing the ColumnHeaderTapCommand and then adding / removing the necessary [SortDescriptors](http://www.telerik.com/help/windows-8-xaml/datagrid-sorting-overview.html) manually. More information about DataGrid commands can be found [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/windows-8-xaml/datagrid-commands-overview.html). The glyph in the column header can be shown through the Column.SortDirection property.
Also, the suggested approach is very suitable and in the future we intend to extend the current logic to allow the SortDescriptors to use this mapping in the templated columns.

Best regards,
Ivaylo